# Getting warning message when allocating memory using pci_alloc_conssitent

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, pci

I have a requirement to allocate **128K memory** of **4K** aligned of **64 chunks**. Currentyl using `pci_alloc_consistent()` as allocated `phy_addr` needs to have **DMA capability**. When i do this, i get the below warning message. Does this mean my request failed?

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at mm/page_alloc.c:2045 __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8d9/0x940() (Tainted: P           ----------------  )
Hardware name: ProLiant DL165 G5
Modules linked in: vgchal(P+)(U) vgcport(P)(U) autofs4 sunrpc cpufreq_ondemand powernow_k8 freq_table mperf ipt_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables ip6t_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_state nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables ipv6 uinput tg3 vgcinit(P)(U) vgcdebug(P)(U) sg microcode k10temp amd64_edac_mod edac_core edac_mce_amd i2c_piix4 i2c_core shpchp ext3 jbd mbcache hpsa cciss sr_mod cdrom ata_generic pata_acpi pata_serverworks sata_svw dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
Pid: 2448, comm: insmod Tainted: P           ----------------   2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
[<ffffffff81069b77>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x87/0xc0
[<ffffffff81069bca>] ? warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[<ffffffff81124069>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8d9/0x940
[<ffffffff81147fc9>] ? vmap_page_range_noflush+0x279/0x370
[<ffffffff811474da>] ? __insert_vmap_area+0x7a/0xd0
[<ffffffff81010f46>] ? dma_generic_alloc_coherent+0xa6/0x160
[<ffffffff8103bb89>] ? gart_alloc_coherent+0x49/0x140
[<ffffffffa00ee5e5>] ? dbh_hal_init+0x105/0x410 [vgchal]
[<ffffffffa00ee805>] ? dbh_hal_init+0x325/0x410 [vgchal]
[<ffffffffa0113095>] ? hal_module_init+0x95/0xa0 [vgchal]
[<ffffffff81096e75>] ? __blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x65/0x80
[<ffffffffa0113000>] ? hal_module_init+0x0/0xa0 [vgchal]
[<ffffffff8100204c>] ? do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x1d0
[<ffffffff810af641>] ? sys_init_module+0xe1/0x250
[<ffffffff8100b0f2>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

As i read, `pci_alloc_consistent()` should be able to allocate more than **128K memory** but couldn't find what  is the max it can do. Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please specify the version of the kernel. It will be easier to find that warning in the kernel sources this way and see what is going on.

Comment: My kernel version where it is run is 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64. Does this tell pci_alloc_consistent() failed ?

Comment: IIRC, pci_alloc_consistent() should return NULL if it fails. The warning could be about something else. Unfortunately, I do not have the sources for that very kernel at hand and the vanilla kernel 2.6.32 seems to be different from yours.

Comment: The closest warning I can see is in __alloc_pages_slowpath (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L2386) which is called from __alloc_pages_nodemask(). It is emitted if too much memory is requested. But I am not sure if it is the case in your system: 128 K is not that much.

Comment: Thanks folks for the answers. If this is warning for too much memory allocation, i was expecting it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend a kernel upgrade, if possible.

`2.6.32-220.el6` was the initial (buggy) kernel release shipped with RHEL 6.2 (*which has been superseded by EL6.3 and 6.4*). If you can, try to move to the last release of the 6.2 kernel, `kernel-2.6.32-220.23.1.el6`,assuming you need to remain on the 6.2 OS release.